# Find the three positive values of p for which the equation $px^2-4x+1=0$ will have rational roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> > Question: Find the three positive values of p for which the equation $$px^2-4x+1=0$$
> >
> > will have rational roots.

---

My attempt (Algebraically):

Usually if it has to have rational roots then the discriminant must equal zero so

$$b^2 - 4ac = 0$$

$$ (-4)^4-4(p)(1)=0$$

$$ 16-4p = 0$$

$$ p = 4 $$

But the answers given are $3 , \frac{7}{4} , \frac{15}{4}$ how do they get that algebraically?

Comment: The discriminant might also be a perfect square

Comment: **The** three positive values is a bit strange since there are infinitely many.

Comment: I guess $p$ is supposed to be a positive **integer**. Then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I agree with André Nicolas, the question is poorly phrased as there are infinitely made answers.

Answer (score 2):

To have rational roots , the discriminant must be perfect square

$$\implies16-4p=a^2\iff p=\dfrac{16-a^2}4$$  where $a$ is rational

If $p=0\iff a^2=16$ the equation won't have both roots finite

Comment: So what numbers would I substitute in to get the answers given?

Comment: @dydxx, You will have infinitely many solutions. You can substitute any rational number. They have substituted with $a=1,2,3$

Comment: Thank you! I learnt something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the original and solving for x, we get
$$px^2-4x+1=0$$

$$x=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-4(p)(1)}}{2p}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-p}}{p}$$
From this is appears that there are many answers where $4-p$ is a perfect square but one is bogus.

$$p=0\implies x=\frac{2+2}{0}\not\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$p=3\implies x=\frac{2\pm1}{3}=\big\{1, \frac{1}{3}\big\}\quad \land\quad p=4\implies x=\frac{2+0}
{4}=\frac{1}{2}\qquad$$

$$p=-5\implies x=\frac{2+\pm3}{-5}=\big\{-1,\frac{1}{5}\big\}\quad \land\quad p=-12\implies x=\frac{2\pm4}{-12}=\big\{\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{6}\big\}$$
$$p=-21\implies x=\frac{2\pm5}{-21}=\big\{\frac{-1}{3},\frac{1}{7}\big\}\quad \land\quad p=-32\implies x=\frac{2\pm6}{-32}=\big\{\frac{-1}{4},\frac{1}{8}\big\}$$

Solving for p: we get $$p=\frac{4x-1}{x^2}$$
$$x=1\implies p=\frac{3}{1}\qquad x=2\implies p=\frac{7}{4}\qquad x=3\implies p=\frac{11}{9}\qquad x=4\implies p=\frac{15}{16}$$

It looks like there are infinite answers with $x$ as the independent variable but I don't know if they will fit back into the original solution for $x$.